# Solr query emulates exactly match

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I use solr to make a short query with brand. I want the equal match, but understand that it is impossible in the Lucene.
I tried some hardcoded query just for tests

```
myBrand:2\+2 and myBrand:\+
```

I get 2:2, seems and condition not working or not so how I am expect?

Also, i try fq

```
myBrand:2\+2 with a fq of myBrand:\+
```

Now, no results at all.

I use Solr 5 and make all tests in the Solr web interface.
Is there some method to get the best matching of some short brands, nicknames and etc, when I no need too much eristics and want strong equal matching? Or anyway I have to filter results in my own code after solr query executed?

[image: query by fields]

[image: query with filter]

[image: query with filter2]

**UPDATED**

Changes in a schema resolved my issues.
Now it is working for the queries `2+2` like a charm.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Can you put sample stored data and your searched query both ?

Comment: @iNikkz done! Do not pay attention about content, but you can easy see that there is output like this `2:2`, its not what i want(first screen short), but when i can try to filter it by `+` symbol, there is no results at all(second one)-( What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equal matches are not impossible. You just have to use a field type that retains the exact value, such as StrField or a TextField with KeywordTokenizer (if you want to make it case insensitive).

Matching would be `field:"Exact value"` or any regular query syntax. The reason why Solr/Lucene wouldn't do an "exact" match is that the regular TextField definitions in the example breaks the text into separate tokens.

For filters you usually want the exact value (both for a facet and for the `fq`, so you can filter the results exactly), so this is not a Lucene limitation, but something introduced by the type of fields you're working with.

The solution might be to have the same content in many fields (one to search against for regular text queries) and one to filter and facet on. Use `copyField` to get the same values into several fields from the same source field.

Comment: Thank you, i know about value break, but my value `2\\+2` without spaces. Maybe i can query some results with query `2\\+2` and after filter it by `+` symbol, i think it excludes the results like this `2 - 2` or `2 : 2`, but i cant make it working in solr web interface, my query is `2\\+2` and the fq is `\\+`

Comment: But how that's being split depends on the analysis chain for the field. If you have a analysis chain that splits on + (and only keeps the '2' and '2' tokens), anything querying in the same manner will match. You have to tweak the analysis chain to split the text into the tokens you want to match, for example by only splitting by whitespace (with the whitespace tokenizer or the worddelimiterfilter)